# Rails dynamic method name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to have dynamic method names like `usd_to_eur` `eur_to_usd`

i have `currencies  = ['uah','rur','usd','eur']` and want to mix it

i try to do it with `define_method` but not sure how to do it correctly.

Comment: It hardly depends on the actual body of these methods. Do they have smth in common?

Comment: in common i guess only `_to_`, `currency1_to_currency2`

Comment: I was asking about _method bodies_.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
class MyClass
  CURRENCIES = %w|uah rur usd eur|
  CURRENCIES.permutation(2).each do |(c1, c2)|
    define_method(:"#{c1}_to_#{c2}") do
      puts "Hi, I am #{__callee__} method"
    end
  end
end
```

Now you have 12 methods defined. E.g.:

```
MyClass.new.eur_to_usd
#⇒ Hi, I am eur_to_usd method
```

Comment: great answer @mudasobwa